# isomorphisms induced on $H_*$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

$X=X_1\cup X_2$, $A=X_1\cap X_2$. Show that $(X_1,A)\hookrightarrow(X,X_2)$ induces an isomorphism on $H_*$ if and only if $(X_2,A)\hookrightarrow(X,X_1)$ induces an isomorphism on $H_*$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't know how to make commutative diagrams on this website, but here goes.  The inclusion $(X_1, A) \hookrightarrow (X, X_2)$ factors through inclusions $(X_1, A) \hookrightarrow (X, A) \hookrightarrow (X, X_2)$, and the same for $(X_2, A) \hookrightarrow (X, A) \hookrightarrow (X, X_1)$.  Apply $H_*$ to these commutative triangles and put them together with $H_*(X, A)$ in the center.  Now apply what Tammo tom Dieck calls the "sum lemma", 11.1.2 in his book which I am just pasting below.

[image: Sum Lemma]

- Tammo tom Dieck, *Algebraic topology*, European Mathematical Society, 2008.

Comment: Does short exact at $(i,j)$ mean that that $(i,j)$ is exact and $j$ is onto and $i$ is injective?

Comment: @StefanH, yes, that's right.