# Homology sequence of the pair $(X,A)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

So I know that the following sequence is exact

$$\cdots\rightarrow H_q(A)\rightarrow H_q(X)\rightarrow H_q(X,A)\rightarrow H_{q-1}(A)\rightarrow\cdots$$

And I am confused about a particular question. Namely, let us first define $X=X_1\cup X_2$ and $A=X_1\cap X_2$. The question then tells us to use an exact sequence of triples to show that if the inclusion $(X_1,A)\rightarrow (X,X_2)$ induces an isomorphism in homology then the same holds for the inclusion $(X_2,A)\rightarrow (X,X_1)$.

My first question is whether the induced isomorphism of the first inclusion map referring to $H_q(X_1,A)\rightarrow H_q(X_2,A)$ or is it referring to a chain isomorphism between the induced homology sequences as given above.

If it is the first I don't see how were supposed to show it since I'm only given the snake lemma and the splitting lemma to use.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365259/isomorphisms-induced-on-h