# How to show excisive triad symmetric from the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra, diagram-chasing

Definition of excisive triad: $(X;X_1,X_2)$ is an excisive triad if the inclusion $(X_1,X_1\cap X_2)\rightarrow (X,X_2)$ induces isomorphism in relative homology.

The definition is not symmetric in $X_1$ and $X_2$, but I would like to show if $(X;X_1,X_2)$ is an excisive triad then so is $(X;X_2,X_1)$ from the axiom. I try the following triple sequences in $X,X_1,X_1\cap X_2$ and $X,X_2,X_1\cap X_2$:

[image]

The green arrows are isomorphisms by assumption and we would like to show the red arrows are isomorphisms. We can split the two triple sequences, so I know the red is composite of mono and epi. But now I get stuck. What further information can we deduce from this?

Comment: This does not appear to be the usual definition of "excisive triad." Where does this definition come from?

Comment: @JohnPalmieri I use the definition from this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRzpaGb9j_Q&list=PL2Rb_pWJf9JqgIR6RR3VFF2FwKCyaUUZn&index=19&t=147s

Comment: How about [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2006804/isomorphism-induced-on-homology)?

Comment: @Thorgott Oh thanks for letting me know. Very appreciated.